# making an element "fill" available height

Tags: css, position

I'm making a window of sorts that is `position:absolute;`.

As seen [here on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ojuceq) the 'window' has a titlebar and its contents:

```
<div class="l">
<div class="t">
<h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class="x">
    <!--contents-->
</div>
</div>
```

my styles are as follows:

```
div.l{position:absolute;background:#aaf;width:70%;height:200px;padding:1em;}
div.t{padding:1px;background:#af9;}
div.x{padding:1em;background:#a87;height:100%;overflow:auto;}
```

What I'm having a problem with is making div `x` take up all of the available space and `overflow:auto;` into a scrollable area.

Since div `l` has a definite size I can apply `overflow:auto;` to it and have a scrollable area but the whole title, `div.t`, scrolls as well, [seen here](http://jsbin.com/uwukat).

---

I need div `x` to fill the remaining space until the bottom `1em` padding so I can use `overflow:auto;` on it.

Is there anyway to do this without making `div.x` absolutely positioned? or at least without knowing the height of `div.t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's fairly clear now that the answer is no, it's not possible to get `div.x` to fill the remaining height.

Maybe CSS3 flexbox can accomplish this, but that was out of the scope of the question when I asked it, and probably belongs in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would only be possible if you set height for `div.t`. Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gmncc/

Comment: and then remove padding on div `l`, yeah that's what I was thinking, or as I mentioned, using absolute positioning. Let's hope someone can prove us both wrong! :)